# How to add icons to the android context menu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

How to add icons to the android context menu?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370905/how-to-show-icons-in-context-menu-in-android maybe it helps

Answer (score 3):

[Context Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) do not support icons.

Comment: Actually your link shows a screenshot with an icon next to the text in the context menu...